# Fullscreen not working in Android App

Tags: android, fullscreen

At the beginning I had problems with the Title Bar, the theme had no effect on it.

So adding the line `getActionBar().hide()` in my `onCreate()` method in the main activity fixed this !

Now I am told to add the line

`getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`

to the `onCreate()` method of my main activity (the activity I am trying to affect) and nothing is happening.

I have tried setting the theme to .FULLSCREEN and nothing.

What I get is a black frame around the app like this:

[image]

Now, this is not an emulator problem, the same thing happens when I run it on my Samsung Galaxy.

Why the black frame !! :'(

Comment: " the theme had no effect on it." After this line I stopped. Theme have the right effect if you will define it proparly.

Comment: It will be helpful if you will write question about what you done and what not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check if you don't have any margin/padding in your xml file ? (and could you post code of the part you're having trouble with if it's not a margin/padding problem?)

Comment: Yes, my relative layout had padding by default. Thanks !